# How to save a lil_matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to make a large (300K * 300K) and sparse (non-zero proportion about 1e-6) matrix.

And I need to frequently change a whole row to zero (like `matrix[i_row, :] = 0`).

So maybe `lil_matrix` is my option.

But I also have to save this matrix to disk. I don't know why, but `scipy.sparse.save_npz()` doesn't support `lil_matrix`.

So how can I save this matrix?

Comment: Transform to one of the supported formats and back if needed. As this should be O(nnz) it's hopefully not much overhead compared to the whole concept of *serialization*.

Comment: `save_npz` saves the matrices as a set of `numpy` arrays in a `npz` zip archive.  For `coo` and `csr` that means 3 numeric arrays.  `lil` stores its data as two `object` dtype arrays, each containing one list per row.  That's enough different from the others that the devs chose not to implement it.  But you could save an `lil` with `pickle`.